# SQL: 1 to 1 relationship with 3 tables - Is it possible to have 1 key referencing 2 different table id's (keys)?)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I couldn't find anything for my example and don't really know how to title it.

Basically, I have 3 tables:

```
Workers
Shop
Warehouse
```

A worker can either work at a Shop, or at a Warehouse, but never in both of them.

I've been told I should make a 1 to 1 relationship between the Shop and the Warehouse, where a table(?) will be created, which will be called "WorkingLocation", which will hold a **workingLocationId** and an extra ID to indicate if it is either a Shop, or a Warehouse. Something like this I assume:

```
Worker
workerId
name
workingLocationId

Shop
shopId
name

Warehouse
warehouseId
name

WorkingLocation
workingLocationId
shopOrWarehouseId
```

Where **shopOrWarehouseId** knows if it is either a shop, or a warehouse.

I might be mistaken on what the 1 to 1 relationship was for, and might be remembering it wrong, but I basically want to be able to tell where the worker is working at, knowing he can work either on a shop or on a warehouse, but never in both.

***I want to know in therms of CREATE TABLE***

```
CREATE TABLE Worker
(
    workerId Number(2) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name Varchar2(25) NOT NULL,
    workingLocationId REFERENCES WorkingLocation(workingLocationId) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Shop
(
    shopId Number(2) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name Varchar2(25) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Warehouse
(
    warehouseId Number(2) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name Varchar2(25) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE WorkingLocation
(
    workingLocationId Number(2) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    shopOrWarehouseId REFERENCES (Shop(shopId), Warehouse(warehouseId)) -- I want to know how to do this, if it is possible
);
```

Is this possible? If not, how can I make something similiar?

(My teacher told me about it but it was quite a good amount of time ago, and as I had to study for exams I have forgotten how it worked, I believe he told that it would know if it is repeated or not and it was like having two tables or something)

***I am using sql developer***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of a "one-of" relationship.  For only two examples, two separate columns is probably the simplest solution:

```
CREATE TABLE Shops (
    shopId Number(2) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name Varchar2(25) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Warehouses (
    warehouseId Number(2) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name Varchar2(25) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Workers (
    workerId Number(2) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name Varchar2(25) NOT NULL,
    shopId Number(2) references shops(shopId),
    warehouseId Number(2) references warehouses(warehouseId),
    check ( (shopId is not null and warehouseId is null) or
            (shopId is null and warehouseId is not null)
          )
);
```

The fourth table does not really help.

Comment: Gordon is right. Another option in the workers table is to have a single ID and a TYPE column, where type is either 'SHOP' or 'WAREHOUSE'.  I think your teach is talking about an "intersection" entity, which is used to resolve a many-to-many relationship between tables.

Comment: I guess I'll use this then, will check about intersections first and if it still not what I trying to find, I'll use this. Thank you!

Comment: Alternatively the business might prefer to maintain a single table of sites, and simply categorise each one as a shop, warehouse, bar etc. The only problem would be for multi-use sites - but then perhaps Shops and Warehouses could become separate tables as above but each with a parent site, containing common columns such as address.